# Laravel Asset Path Issue

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I am working on laravel project using Laravel 8 with bootstrap UI. I integrated my bootstrap template locally and all my assets are located in folder public/assets.

In my blade file, I am using the asset method to automatically provide the full path to my CSS or js files

```
    <!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
    <link href="{!!asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')!!}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{!!asset('vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')!!}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{!!asset('vendor/modal-video/css/modal-video.min.css')!!}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{!!asset('vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css')!!}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{!!asset('vendor/aos/aos.css')!!}" rel="stylesheet">
```

It's working fine locally at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

But when I deploy the project over my server, it could not find my assets files. Gives the error of not found / file doesn't exist. But if I add string public before assets then it works. Like

```
public/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

The issue is that I don't want to change things before deploying to the server. Is there a way laravel automatically adjusts the assets path locally as well as on the server too? Otherwise, I have to make changes in some files to make it work with server environment

My htaccess file, Just in case:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]



    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/

    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: No solution yet?

Comment: I have a similar kind of issue, any more solutions to this problem?

Comment: Do you have a similar issue with your server deployment?

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Try this way and check is it working or not

Comment: What's the difference in this method? you are only echoing it without htmlspecialcharacters

Comment: Yes, just try or have you added any .htaccess at root of the project?

Comment: Yes, I added htaccess which just points to public folder

Comment: Okay and with the above code, have you checked? is it working?

Comment: I shared my htaccess too

Comment: No, it doesn't work unless i add public in front of asset

Comment: try once removing the.htaccess and check is it working or not

Comment: No it will not work because i have to tell server via htaccess to point to public folder to render it.

Comment: No solution yet?

Comment: It's not a solution, it will do the same thing shared in question.

Answer (score 0):

First, set your ASSET_URL on .env files (**production server**)

```
ASSET_URL=http://yourwebsite.com/public
```

Second, use ***asset()*** function to your blade file. For example your bootstrap CSS file :

```
<link href="{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```